# Is there a hdfs command to list files in HDFS directory as per timestamp

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a hdfs command to list files in HDFS directory as per timestamp, ascending or descending? By default, `hdfs dfs -ls` command gives unsorted list of files.

When I searched for answers what I got was a workaround i.e. `hdfs dfs -ls /tmp | sort -k6,7`. But is there any better way, inbuilt in `hdfs dfs` commandline?

Comment: -ls -t doesn't do the trick?

Comment: from the doc: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls. `ls -R -t (-r)` give you a list of  all file found in recursive search order by last modification time. -r is to reverse order

Comment: tried it on hadoop 2.6 without success however...

Comment: I can see only options `[-d] [-h] [-R]` on Hadoop 2.6

Comment: yeah saw that to. if you can upgrade to 2.7 you have a command, otherwise there is no way whithout a pipe

Answer (score 65, accepted):

No, there is no other option to sort the files based on datetime.
If you are using hadoop version < 2.7, you will have to use sort -k6,7 as you are doing:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp | sort -k6,7
```

And for hadoop 2.7.x [ls command](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls) , there are following options available :

```
Usage: hadoop fs -ls [-d] [-h] [-R] [-t] [-S] [-r] [-u] <args>

Options:
-d: Directories are listed as plain files.
-h: Format file sizes in a human-readable fashion (eg 64.0m instead of 67108864).
-R: Recursively list subdirectories encountered.
-t: Sort output by modification time (most recent first).
-S: Sort output by file size.
-r: Reverse the sort order.
-u: Use access time rather than modification time for display and sorting.
```

So you can easily sort the files:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -t -R (-r) /tmp
```

Comment: Here in answer what is sort k6,7 , Does it sort based on sixth column