# How to get recently created partitions in a Hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning, pyhive, hive-metastore

I have a table called EMPLOYEE with columns ID, NAME, DESIGNATION, CITY, COUNTRY, CONTINENT. With 3 level partitioning on CONTINENT, COUNTRY, CITY.
Now I need to know recently created partitions say after a specific timestamp.
Note : Assuming access to mysql metastore is not provided.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095790/how-to-find-the-most-recent-partition-in-hive-table --check this

Comment: I'm expecting something where the partitions can be listed according to the creation or last accessed time. More over my partition column is not timestamp or or date type. If I say I need partitions that are created after feb7 11AM then the output should have only those which are created after that time.

Comment: sort your hdfs directory which contains the partitions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022749/is-there-a-hdfs-command-to-list-files-in-hdfs-directory-as-per-timestamp

Comment: Wow great, I'll update you

Comment: Its working good. Thank you