# How to delete the most recently created files in multiple HDFS directories?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hql, hadoop-partitioning

I made a mistake and have added a few hundred part files to a table partitioned by date. I am able to see which files are new (these are the ones I want to remove). Most cases I've seen on here relate to deleting files older than a certain date, but I only want to remove my most recent files.

For a single day, I may have 3 files as such, and I want to only remove the newfile. I can tell it's new because of the update timestamp when I use hadoop fs -ls

```
/this/is/my_directory/event_date1_newfile_20191114
/this/is/my_directory/event_date1_oldfile_20190801
/this/is/my_directory/event_date1_oldfile_20190801
```

I have many dates, so I'll have to complete this for event_date2, event_date3, etc etc, always removing the 'new_file_20191114' from each date.

The older dates are from August 2019, and my newfiles were updated yesterday, on 11/14/19.

I feel like there should be an easy/quick solution to this, but I'm having trouble finding the reverse case from what most folks have asked about.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm afraid I don't think there's a one-liner for this. Should only be a few lines of Bash though.

Comment: does all of your new files have same timestamp ? or  timestamp of new files is greater than some specified time ?

Comment: @Strick yes, exactly - I've been able to make some progress using:
`hdfs dfs -ls /tmp | sort -k6,7` from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022749/is-there-a-hdfs-command-to-list-files-in-hdfs-directory-as-per-timestamp

So I now have my list of specific files I need to remove, and I'm now trying to find a way to bulk remove a pre-created list of files

Comment: I will post answer

Comment: I have posted and answer please check if it solves your purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS mentioned in your answer you have got the list of files that needs to be deleted.
Create a simple script redirect the output to temp file

like this

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp | sort -k6,7 > files.txt
```

**Please note sort -k6,7 this will give all the files but in sorted order of timestamp. I am sure you dont want to delete all thus you can select the top n files that needs to be deleted lets say 100**

then you can update your command to

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp | sort -k6,7 | head -100 |  awk '{print $8}' > files.txt
```

or if you know specific timestamp of your new files then you can try below command

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp | sort -k6,7 | grep "<exact_time_stamp>" |  awk '{print $8}' > files.txt
```

Then read that file and delete all files one by one

```
while read file; do
  hdfs -rm $file
  echo "Deleted $file" >> deleted_files.txt #this is to track which files have been deleted

done <files.txt
```

So you complete script can be like

```
#!/bin/bash

 hdfs dfs -ls /tmp | sort -k6,7 | grep "<exact_time_stamp>" |  awk '{print $8}' > files.txt

 while read file; do
     hdfs -rm $file
     echo "Deleted $file" >> deleted_files.txt #this is to track which files have been deleted

   done <files.txt
```

Comment: looks like your solution using `head -100` is getting me even closer. I know exactly how many files I need to delete (the most recent 181 files) and with the way it sorted, i'm actually having to use `tail -181`. And so if I know the exact number of files, I don't think I need to grep for the timestamp, is that correct?  so...for my purposes, does this look appropriate?

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

hadoop fs -ls /my_directory/* | sort -k6,7 | tail -181 > files.txt

 while read file; do
     hadoop fs -rm $file
     echo "Deleted $file" >> deleted_files.txt #this is to track which files have been deleted

   done <files.txt`

Comment: yes if you know exact files then no need to grep. but for safe side just check if the output of "hdfs dfs -ls /tmp | sort -k6,7 | grep "<exact_time_stamp>" | wc -l" is also or 180 or so .. that is for rechecking only ..rest you can proceed with your tail approach

Comment: please see i am also using awk '{print $8}' to get exact file path instead of other columns you need to validate this also .. so update this also in your command

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the formatting for grep but my timestamps are either `2019-11-14 21:03` or `2019-11-14 21:04`  all 181 files were added within this two second range

Comment: hdfs dfs -ls /tmp | sort -k6,7 | grep "2019-11-14 21:03" | wc -l similarly for hdfs dfs -ls /tmp | sort -k6,7 | grep "2019-11-14 21:04" | wc -l and check if the some of both output comes 181

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202418/discussion-between-strick-and-phenderbender).